# Join two data frames by searching & matching strings

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames
**df1**

```
+-------+---------+  
|   Id  |  Title  |
+-------+---------+  
|   1   |   AAA   |
|   2   |   BBB   |
|   3   |   CCC   |
+-------+---------+
```

AND

**df2**

```
+-------+---------------+------------------------------------+
|   Id  |      Sub      |               Body                 |
+-------+---------------+------------------------------------+  
|   1   |   some sub1   | some mail body AAA some text here  |
|   2   |   some sub2   | some text here BBB continues here  |
|   3   |   some sub3   | some text AAA present here         |
|   4   |   some sub4   | AAA string is present here also    |
|   5   |   some sub5   | CCC string is present here         |
+-------+---------------+------------------------------------+
```

I want to match the `Title` from **df1** with the `Body` column of the **df2**,
if title string is present in Body column, then both the rows should be joined, the output data frame should be like:

**df3**

```
+----------+---------------+------------------------------------+
|   Title  |      Sub      |               Body                 |
+----------+---------------+------------------------------------+  
|   AAA    |   some sub1   | some mail body AAA some text here  |
|   BBB    |   some sub2   | some text here BBB continues here  |
|   AAA    |   some sub3   | some text AAA present here         |
|   AAA    |   some sub4   | AAA string is present here also    |
|   CCC    |   some sub5   | CCC string is present here         |
+----------+---------------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: @DAXaholic, Thanks for your reply. Your example is working perfectly with your code, however when i m trying to add my actual data i m getting the following error. `Error in grepl(df1$title[idx], df2$body) : invalid 'pattern' argument`. I m sorry, i missed one more thing in my question, in the **Title** i have string like "AAA BB" not just "AAA". I tried your code with the data "AAA BB" it is giving the following error `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0`.

Comment: I updated my answer with another approach when we cannot assume that each title matches some rows - hope that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution could look like this, although more experienced R users will probably come up with better answers

```
# set up test data
df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
                  id = 1:3,
                  title = c('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'))
df2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
                  id = 1:5,
                  sub = c('some sub1', 'some sub2', 'some sub3', 'some sub4', 'some sub5'),
                  body = c('some mail body AAA some text here',
                           'some text here BBB continous here',
                           'some text AAA present here',
                           'AAA string is present here also',
                           'CCC string is present here'))

# join data frames
df.list <- lapply(1:nrow(df1), function (idx) cbind(title=df1[idx,2], df2[grepl(df1$title[idx], df2$body), 2:3]))
do.call('rbind', df.list)
```

which will result in the following output

```
  title       sub                              body
1   AAA some sub1 some mail body AAA some text here
3   AAA some sub3        some text AAA present here
4   AAA some sub4   AAA string is present here also
2   BBB some sub2 some text here BBB continous here
5   CCC some sub5        CCC string is present here
```

---

#### Update due to comment:

If we cannot rely on the fact that each title will match some rows in `df2` then you might want to do something like this

```
# set up test data
df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
                  id = 1:4,
                  title = c('AAA', 'AAA BB', 'BBB', 'CCC'))
df2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
                  id = 1:5,
                  sub = c('some sub1', 'some sub2', 'some sub3', 'some sub4', 'some sub5'),
                  body = c('some mail body AAA some text here',
                           'some text here BBB continous here',
                           'some text AAA present here',
                           'AAA string is present here also',
                           'CCC string is present here'))

MergeByTitle <- function(title.idx) {
  df2.hits <- df2[grepl(df1$title[title.idx], df2$body), 2:3]
  if (nrow(df2.hits) > 0)
    cbind(title=df1[title.idx,2], df2.hits)
}

# join data frames
df.list <- lapply(1:nrow(df1), MergeByTitle)
do.call('rbind', df.list)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It helped,  this is exactly what i was looking for.